# C Program to Store ttyUSB* devices in an array

Tags: linux, c

AM having a C program which uses system to list /dev/ttyUSB* devices how can I store them in an array and process.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    system("ls /dev/ttyUSB*");
    printf("Done");
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: If you say *what* are you trying to achieve, you might get some recommendations on how to do that.

Comment: Also, you'll probably get better answers to programming questions on Stack Overflow than on Unix & Linux.

Answer (score 4):

Using `system` for these things is a bad idea.

First of all, you have to [Parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), which you should avoid.

Apart from that, this will be quite inefficient. starting programs is rather slow, but you are running a program (written in C), that starts another program (written in C) which calculates *something* and renders this *something* into a human-readable form, and then you have to parse the human-readable form to find out what the original *something* was...

A better way is to do the shortcut can "calculate the *something*" directly:

check out [`glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html)

Comment: @slm, yes thats why i gave the link "first of all".

Comment: Sorry missed your comment!

Comment: … and you can't access the output from `system` anyway.